# Lazarus/SqlLite3 Не находит столбец

Tags: sql, база-данных, lazarus, gameserver

Делаю небольшую игру. Есть БД с таблицей: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть метод создающий Броню на заказ:

```
function TDataBaseManager.GetHeroArmor(nameOfArmor: String; armorType: XAbsArmorType; equipType: XAbsEquipmentType): TEquipment;
var i: XAbsParameter;
    armor: TArmor;
begin
  armor := TArmor.Create;
  SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM '+eEquipmentType[equipType]+'Params WHERE name = '+nameOfArmor;
  SQLQuery1.Open;
  for i:=low(XAbsParameter) to high(XAbsParameter) do begin
    if (i<>Defence) and (i<>WeaponDamage) then begin
      armor._params[i] := SQLQuery1.FieldByName(pParameter[i]).AsFloat;
      end
    else armor._params[i] := 0;
  end;
```

Проблема возникает тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно название колонки передаётся методу верно Helm_11, но после команды "SQLQuery1.Open;" выдаёт ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это вообще это возможно. Для меня это на столько нелогично... . Но всего скорее я просто что то не понимаю.
Помогите. Буду очень признателен!

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас криво формируется SQL запрос. Можете показать, какая строка улетает на выполнение? Т.е. что получаете в переменную **SQLQuery1.SQL.Text** перед открытием

Comment: Вы передаёте своё `Helm_11` именно как имя поля (колонки), а вовсе даже не как значение, которое хранится в поле записи. То есть в SQLQuery1.SQL.Text следует получить `SELECT * FROM table.column WHERE name = 'value'`. Обратите внимание на обрамляющие значение кавычки (и не вздумайте там влепить двойную кавычку).

Comment: Что такое `pParameter`?

Comment: Странно. Перед запросом Шлема, вызывался похожий метод на оружие, только там тоже самое работало корректно: SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT '+wWeaponType[weaponType]+' FROM weaponParams WHERE tier = '+tier;

Comment: *там тоже самое работало корректно* Там поди передаваемое значение - числовое, да? ну так оно, в отличие от строкового, кавычек как бы не требует.. блин, учите уже матчасть!

Comment: Да, числовое) тогда не понимаю как
задать поиск столбца в котором поле это строка?

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Решил проблему с помощью оператора LIKE.

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM '+eEquipmentType[equipType]+'Params WHERE name LIKE "'+nameOfArmor+'"';
```

Тема закрыта.